# Standalone mode exit

Tags: fitnesse, dbfit

I want to have standalone mode and flow mode in the same suite but it shows error such as "Ambiguity between: fixture dbfit.fixture.ExecuteProcedure AND executeProcedure()".
This is because standalone mode is getting executed and then flow mode.
When I changed the names so that flow mode is executed first and then stand alone mode, it starts working.
Can, anybody tell me how to close standalone mode so that flow mode can be started.